# C# Two String Comparison False Even Though Same String Content

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried everything i can think of to get these two strings to return false when comparing them including trimming white-space as well as normalizing them.

Here is the statement:

```
 if(factory[0].ToString().Trim().Normalize() != newfactory[0].ToString().Trim().Normalize())
```

If i write out the contents of each string they are exactly the same:
         KLANG-MA3
         KLANG-MA3

I've tried with and without the trim and normalize. What other things can i try?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried different [StringComparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) values? StringComparison.Ordinal or StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase?

`String.Equals(factory[0].ToString(), newfactory[0].ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal)`

Comment: Write out the int code of each character in both strings and verify nothing funky is going on.

Comment: Sorry dup comment...didn't carefully read opiants

Comment: Are you sure there are no non-visible Whitespaces?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Good idea. It may very well be similar looking characters, but are actually different. Example is `3` and `з` - `A` and `А`

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Just tried the Ordinal comparison. Still didn't work. I will try writing out to integers next.

Comment: Assuming it isn't the operator, Have you checked to see if these string s are Interned?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Dump both strings as a sequence of utf-16 code-units. One of them might contain invisible characters or unicode look-alikes. @dweeb Why would interning matter here? Both sides are statically typed as string, so it'll use value comparison.

Comment: What is the type of the object? Is ToString overridden? What is the collection type? When strange things happen these kinds of specifics may help.

Answer (score 0):

This is false if you compare with != not equal, the same value,
you are asking are this values different, the answer is false. which mean they are the same.